# Is there a way to use RSS aggregator to follow a single Google Reader folder?

Tags: rss, google-reader

Is there a way to follow a single folder in Google Reader using another RSS aggregator?
Google listen does this for podcasts but I was hopping to gpodder for that without creating a new account.

Answer (score 1):

Google Reader -> "Manage subscriptions" -> "Folders and Tags" -> (click on the feed icon of the folder/tag to make it public) -> "view public page", and you'll find the "Atom Feed" to subscribe to using your preferred feed reader.